# Save the output dataframe from docker to a local machine

Tags: python, docker, csv

Tried with `{WORKDIR}` & replaced `{ADD}` with `{COPY}` in Dockerfile. Still the CSV file is not being saved in the local folded in the local machine, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to write to a host file from the Docker container, first [volume mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) a directory into the running container.

For example, we can mount the current working directory into a directory in the container:

```
$ docker run -v $(PWD):/pwd_in_container -it --rm busybox touch /pwd_in_container/test
```

Then the file we created in the container will be available on the host:

```
$ ls test
test
```